# synchronous UIWebView stopLoading for immediate execution

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Is there any way I can stop the loading of the UIWebView (using stopLoading) and return control to the user right at that moment when I call it? I understand the run loop still needs to end its cycle but I simply want the same effect I am getting when I stop the loading manually (with a button).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean, but would it make sense for you to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`?

More details in [NSObject class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).